# php - check if files exists in folder on network/lan

Tags: php, file-exists

I want to check if files exists in the network folder (eg. path = "U:\abc\def\") using php.

I tried to use following:

```
if(file_exists("U:/abc/def/400abc.doc")) {
    echo "YES";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

I get NO. I also tried path = "//abc-drive/folder-main/abc/def/400abc.doc" but still it doesn't work.

The files are on a network/shared folder and NOT in subfolders from where php server runs

Can anyone please tell HELP?

Regards

Comment: Did you try path = "\\abc-drivefolder-main\abc\def\400abc.doc"

Comment: Your slashes are leaning the wrong direction for Windows.

Comment: does the account PHP's running under have permissions to access that drive and folder tree?

Comment: @Dan Grossman: in php you can use either `/` or `\ `. They behave absolutely in the same way.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I tried both ways but no luck. Yes my apache has permission to read and write in that folder. Regards

Comment: Did you try adding file:// in front of it? file://U://abc/def/400abc.doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work if PHP has [safe_mode](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) enabled. Try setting [`safe_mode_include_dir`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-include-dir) to add an exception, and reference the location with the syntax  `\\computername\share\filename`.

Comment: the safe_mode feature is disabled in php **5.4**, I am using php **5.5**. What needs to be done in my case?

Comment: heh, reviving a 9 year old answer? PHP5 is no longer getting security updates. _Don't use it at all_ is the only right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URI format. file://U:/abc/def/400abc.doc

Answer (score 0):

Change FASTCGI Setting in server
[FASTCGI Setting] -> open ...php-cgi.ex ->
FastCGI Property -> Advanced Setting　-> protocol -> Change [NamedPipe] to [TCP].
I have same error with you, I tried it and success. GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

If file_exists is returning false for a file or folder on a Windows network drive, try the following:

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Locate the following key - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\RestrictNullSessAccess
3. Change its value from 1 to 0.
4. Restart your computer.
5. Double check your network drive is connected.
6. Retry your script - this time file_exists should return true.